# Virtuemart 3 подтверждение заказа в корзине

Tags: php, jquery, joomla, virtuemart

Недавно начал работать с Virtuemart 3 для Joomla. Заметил неудобную функцию как "Подтверждение заказа" - добавляешь товар в корзину, переходишь к оформлению заказа, заполняешь данные, нажимаешь кнопку "Оформить заказ" - и данная кнопка меняется на "Подтвердить заказ" - думаю, для моего сайта абсолютно ненужная функция. Вводит пользователя в заблуждение. После запуска сайта уже массы жалоб, что они оформляют заказ, но мы не перезваниваем им, а они просто не замечают, что нужно еще раз подтвердить...

Знаю расширение OnePage - но это тоже не подходит, потому что мой сайт уже много-посещаемый, и OnePage меняет шаблон корзины, а у меня там все по-другому оформлено. Хочу изменить стандартную корзину VM 3.

Comment: Версия какая используется? И можно ссылку на магазин.

Comment: @AndrewHobbit VirtueMart 3.0.12 / Joomla 3.4.8  - это php расширение, ссылку на магазин необязательно

Comment: Да, я знаю что расширение, на двойке сидел, пока на OC не перешел.

Answer (score 3):

Не уверен необходимо ли делать изменения в коде. Скорей всего можно отключить используя админку. Например, как в этой теме https://forum.virtuemart.net/index.php?topic=92103.60

Если же нет, то отключать прийдется через код, допустим как тут
https://snipt.net/jtem/disable-virtuemart-double-confirmation/

Либо же как указано в данной теме https://forum.virtuemart.net/index.php?topic=92103.0

в файле cart.php

Изменить линию

```
->> public function setDataValidation($valid=false) {

       $this->_dataValidated = $valid;
          //       $this->setCartIntoSession();
       }
```

на эту

```
->>  public function setDataValidation($valid=true)
```

Надеюсь это поможет в решении задачи.